# OS X El Capitan: Change the direction of text

Tags: keyboard, macos, text

I remember I used to change the direction of text using keyboard shortcuts (like `Command-Control-Right Arrow`), but it doesn't work anymore.
How can I re-enable it?
I found this [page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21548?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) about this topic from Apple, but none of these work.

Comment: What app are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the System Prefs/Keyboard/Input Sources/Arabic  (or whatever script you are using) and make sure the box for Enable Keyboard Shortcuts is checked.

[image]